# expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not dict: TypeError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, ftplib

I'm getting error when uploading a zip file from s3 bucket to FTP location. Here I'm using the public FTP which we can use anonymous.

Please find the below code

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
print("Loading the function")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ftp = ftplib.FTP("speedtest.tele2.net")
    ftp.login()
    ftp.cwd("/upload")
    print(event)
    src_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    print("Source Bucket name:",src_bucket)
    dest_bucket= "dest-bucket-name-here"
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    filename= ntpath.basename(key)
    print('Received file :{} and fullpath location: {}'.format(filename,key))
    copy_source = {'Bucket': src_bucket,'Key': key}
    bucket = s3.Bucket(dest_bucket)
    ftp.storbinary("STOR " + filename, open(copy_source, 'r'))  # error is as mentioned in title.
```

expected output: File should be uploaded to the FTP path. (As it is a public FTP used for testing purpose, once the file uploaded will be deleted by speedtest automatically.)

Comment: You are passing a dictionary to open function instead of a filename @manisekhar Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

[ftp.storbinary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary) expects a `file object` like a string as an input, but you are passing it a dictionary `copy_source = {'Bucket': src_bucket,'Key': key}`, hence the error `expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not dict: TypeError`

Provide the correct filename( I guess from here `filename= ntpath.basename(key)` and the code should be fine.

So the last line will perhaps change to

```
ftp.storbinary("STOR " + filename, open(filename, 'r'))
```